# Select DB, OLAP solutions for fast web analytics (large data array)

Tags: hadoop, analytics, olap

I have the following problem: my system collects daily ~300M hits from different sites. 
Every has time, user id, type (ad or usual), http address, site id.

There is also an array of users ~ 200M, which has gender, age group and country.

Required to design a system that is based on data by hits could give real-time reports on the hits of different user groups. Like OLAP solutions :-)

For example, to plot graph on hits for girls 15-25 age, from UK, from October to September, 2011.

Which database you recommend to choose, and solution to build OLAP cubes?

I'm looking for opensource solution, like HBase (+ zohmg or cascading) Hypertable or something else (free DWH :-)).

Answer (score 1):

That's massive amount of data, 300Mio daily hits it's only available to a few sectors. This is around 100 Tera (10e2 * 10e9) hits per year, wow !

I don't know of any OLAP like solutions that can handle such amount of data without pre-aggregations, even taking into account the paying solutions. Maybe working around reducing the information of your analytical (aka OLAP) system : getting rid or reducing the size of the dimensions user_id, http address and site id.

Would be curious how do you solve your problem and how did you get the gender, age group of your 200M users :-).

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do this in (close to) real time. You can pre-aggregate over each day. Imagine the following materialized view:

```
CREATE VIEW preAggregatedByDate
SELECT gender, ageGroup, country, date, COUNT(*) AS dailyCount
FROM myTable
GROUP BY date;
```

So you've got a count for each combination of your parameters (gender, age group, and country) over each date. For your query, you'd do something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM preAggregatedByDate
WHERE gender = 'Female' AND ageGroup = '15_25' AND country = 'UK' AND
    date >= '20110901' AND date < '20111101';
```

Obviously, it's not going to be this simple (and you might not get to use SQL and materialized views), but this might be the best way to imagine it if you are familiar with conventional databases. Your actual query is only pulling data from a greatly reduced, pre-aggregated data source.

If you don't mind having to wait a few hours after the end of the day to run queries over that day, the easiest solution may be to use Hadoop to compute the pre-aggregated data and put that into some normal database that you can then run queries on.

Comment: I forgot to mention: a possible problem with pre-aggregating the data is that a user's information may change. For example, if the user relocates to another country, they will still be counted in their previous country for the pre-aggregation you have already done. This may be desirable according to your business rules, or it may not.

Comment: Also: if you want counts of *unique* users (rather than total hits) for each query, then this pre-aggregation will not work.